# Get Xmpp roster list

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xmpp, xmppframework

I use that code to get it

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];
if (queryElement)
{
    NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
    [self.cts removeAllObjects];
    for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *jid = [[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
        [self.cts addObject:jid];
    }
    NSLog(@"\nRoster ID's %@",self.cts);
}
```

Problem is that firstly I get roster list but if it changing I get just jID of user that is removed or added in roster list. My purpose to get complete current roster list. How can I do it?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. please provide sample input and expected output. also, how does this relate to CoreData?

Comment: @Dan Shelly, My purpose is to get roster list for current user for my request or to have it in persistent place

Comment: @Dan Shelly, I am looking to way to do it with core data - to load roster list from it

Comment: describe your problem by providing a simple input and expected output, otherwise your problem (as I see it) is reduced to storing an array in CoreData which is most probably a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems you are using the XMPPFramework - usually the additional information will come in via vCards when they are needed.

If using the CoreData part of the roster (XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage), and you have the roster to be autoFetched, you should get the full roster (depending on the server you are using), and when needed, the vCard for that user (to get the rest of the information).

If you need to get the full one each time, you can tell it manually fetch ([xmppRoster fetchRoster], and it will request a full one (query type get). You can also track these iq's to know when you have received the response to the request (using the XMPPIDTracker).